# Measure a weight by using combination of multiple weight

Tags: java, algorithm

```
 I'm very new to java, so i need a help . here is my problem:
```

I have two weights 1gram and 5 gram. now user will give the weight he/she wants to calculate, and the user will also give the count for 1gram and 5 gram. the program will return true if it can calculate otherwise it will return false. I'm giving you a example:

count for 1 gram is 5(say)
count for 5 gram is 3(say)
weight to measure the  12 gram

by using two 1gram and two 5gram  i can make 12gram. so it will return true.

please help me to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this homework? If yes you should edit your question and add `homework` tag.

Comment: yes I can.but user will give any number of count. user can give less amount of 1gram count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is homework so here are hints for the algorithm for solution

**Addition way**

First you should take out multiples of 5 from the weight to be measured. 
Remainder weight should be equal to number of 1 gram weights.

For example:

> When input is `3x5gm` and `2x1gm` and you want to weigh `12gms`

```
12 / 5 = 2 (5 gram weights)
12 % 5 = 2 (1 gram weights)
```

If these numbers are less than number of weights you have you have the answer.

**Subtraction Way**

First you should take out multiples of 5 from the weight to be measured.

For example:

> When input is `3x5gm` and `2x1gm` and you want to weigh `13gms`

```
13 / 5 = 2 (5 gram weights)
13 % 5 = 3 (1 gram weights)
```

Since you don't have enough weights to do so then you can look if you can manage the remainder with 1 additional 5gm and remaining `5-1gm weights` i.e. `1x5gm` and `5-3=2x1gm weights` so the answer will be `3x5gm` and `2x1gm`